# Copy SELECT data from one table to another

Tags: sql

I have one table called `snapshot_history`. This table records every action that a unit makes (Emergency Vehicle). However, this table purges on a rolling 30 days. (There are so many movements that it would within a year max out space on the server)

However, I need some of that history to be perpetual and not purge. The system isn't mine so I can't redesign the system.

Each night at `2am` I want to copy the changes from the "snapshot_history" table.

How can I do that? I know how to insert and all that, but the issue is the FROM table deletes on a rolling 30 day period.

```
INSERT vehicle
    ,unit
    ,type
    ,STATUS
    ,DATE
    ,TIME
INTO perpetual_snapshot_history
WHERE type = 1
    AND STATUS = 2
```

Comment: You can compare the primary keys between the source table and the target table. If you see difference on the primary keys then insert it on your target (or copied) table. Let me know if you need help on the sql. Thanks.

Comment: does the snapshot history table get updated on a daily basis? you can run a daily batch job to update/insert into your table.

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL 2014

Comment: create event start with a time 2 am and interval every 24 hour!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO [NEW_TABLE] (
    FieldName1
    ,FieldName2
    ,FieldName3
    ,etc etc
    )
SELECT A_Field
    ,A_Field_2
    ,A_Field_3 etc etc
FROM SNAPSHOT_HISTORY
WHERE SPASHOT_HISTORY.CreatedDate >= A_DATE.
```

Be sure to match the fields to the correct columns.